# how do i write assembly in C++ for adding (time test)

Tags: c++, assembly

I want to time how much slower it is if i were to do a simple operation like 1+1 and plus(int l,int r) which does l+r and throws an exception on overflow heres some example code with _C and _V being carry and overflow. The exception code can be written differently if you like.

How do i write it so i can quickly test for carry/overflow and throw an exception if it is true?
I never did jumps (or even some of the basics) in assembly so i a bit clueless even after googling.

This should work in x32 comps. Currently i am running on a Intel Core Duo which has the x86, x86-64 set

```
unsigned int plus(unsigned int l, unsigned int r){
    unsigned int v = l+r;
    if (!_C) return v; 
    throw 1;
}

int plus(int l, int r){
    int v = l+r;
    if (!_V) return v;
    throw 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want C/C++ code to perform these operations, or do you want to know how to do it in x86 assembly language?

In C/C++, determining the carry is easy:

```
int _C = (v < l); // "v < r" works too
```

The overflow is a bit more complicated. Normally overflow is flagged when the two operands have the same sign yet the result has a different sign. On two's complement architectures such as x86, this can be written as:

```
int _V = ((l ^ r) >= 0) && ((l ^ v) < 0);
```

The MSB (sign bit) of `l ^ r` will be 0 if and only if the signs agree, and similarly `l ^ v` will have a nonzero sign bit (=value less than zero) if and only if `l` and `v` have opposite signs.

If you want to write it in assembly, you just do the add and use a `jc` or `jo` respectively to jump to the carry/overflow handler. However, you can't easily throw C++ exceptions from assembly code. The easiest way to do this is probably to write a simple one-line function in C++ that throws the exception and call that from your assembly code. The final asm code will look something like this:

```
    ; Assuming eax=l, ebx=r
    add eax, ebx
    jc .have_carry
    ; Continue computation here...
.have_carry:
    call throw_overflow_exception
```

with the following C++ helper function defined somewhere:

```
extern "C" void throw_overflow_exception()
{
  throw 1; // or some other exception
}
```

You need the `extern C` to disable C++ name mangling for this function. There are other conventions to (e.g. some compilers add an underscore before or after C function names) - this depends on the compiler used and the architecture though.

Comment: how do i write return in between     jc .have_carry and 
.have_carry:
?

Comment: The corresponding x86 opcode is `ret`, which will work for some cases and calling conventions - other calling conventions need more work. It again depends on the compiler.

Comment: Also, please note that calling into an ASM function to do something as simple as integer addition has *significant* overhead - easily more than 10x the cost of the actual addition. Even inline assembler doesn't really help since it usually acts as an optimization barrier to the compiler. You're really best off writing the tests in C/C++. That may generate more instructions than the "direct" ASM equivalent (although it doesn't have to, your compiler might realize what you're doing), but these instructions will participate in compiler optimization, a huge benefit for something this simple.

Comment: i didnt know that. I tried the asm vs no asm and the no asm was faster. I'll write mroe comments in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Shift bit both inputs right by one. Add them both then test the left-most bit.

```
l>>1;
r>>1;
int result = l+r;
if (result>>((sizeof(int)*8)-1)) { /* handle overflow */ }
```

Comment: -edit- i thought results is what i return. You mean use that just to test with. That makes sense. But i still need code in assembly?

Comment: This will only detect carry (unsigned overflow) and does way more work than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test code i end up using

-edit- I tested on VS 2010 outside of the IDE and in GCC. gcc is a lot faster as VC optimizes the variables poorly. (VS c++ moves the register back into V when assembly is used. It doesnt need to do that.) gcc shows little between the 3 test. The results varied from each run so often that they all looked like it was the same test. I couldnt tell. VS showed checking C flag without asm about 3x slower while with asm 6x slower.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    try{
    for(int n=0; n<10; n++){
        volatile unsigned int v, r;
        sscanf("0", "%d", &v);
        sscanf("0", "%d", &r);
        __int64 time = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        __int64 start = __rdtsc();
        for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++)
        {

            v=v+v;
#if 1
            __asm jc e
            continue;
e:
            throw 1;
#endif
        }
        __int64 end = __rdtsc();
        time = end - start;
        printf("time: %I64d\n", time/10000000);
    }
    }
    catch(int v)
    {
        printf("exception");
    }
    return 0;
}
```